# Is it possible to pass a slice of a struct as an interface to a method?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I writing a simple API in Go, using `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`. It ia backed by a database and I am using `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` for querying and updating the database.

I have a number of endpoints that pretty much use the same code to get the data from the database so I am trying to create a single `retrieve` method that works with all of my db types.

So for example, I have the following struct:

```
type Image struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Filename string
}
```

The API declaration has for my route is as follows:

```
func (v1 *ApiV1) getImage(c *gin.Context) {
  var images []db.Image

  httpStatus := v1.retrieve("name", c.Param("name"), &images)

  c.JSON(
    httpStatus,
    images,
  )
}
```

As can be seen I am trying to pass a pointer to the struct that I want the query to populate. As I will need several different enpoints for the different types in the DB, I want to make the `retrieve` method reuseable, so I created it with this signature:

```
func (v1 *ApiV1) retrieve(fieldName string, name string, returnObject *[]interface{}) int {

    // create var to hold the http status
    var httpStatus int = http.StatusOK

    // determine if a name has been passed
    if name == "" {
        v1.app.DB.Find(returnObject)
    } else {

        // look for the name in the database
        v1.app.DB.Where(fieldName+" = ?", name).First(returnObject)

        // if the name cannot be found then set the status to 404
        if len(*returnObject) == 0 {
            httpStatus = http.StatusNotFound
        }
    }

    return httpStatus
}
```

To try and make it 'generic' I have used `*[]interface{}` as the type for the returnObject. (The name is a bit of a misnomer as it is pointer, but it makes it easy to understand that something will be udpated).

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
cannot use &images (type *[]db.Image) as type *[]interface {} in argument to v1.retrieve
```

I fully understand that Go is a strictly typed language, but as I want to be able to reuse my `retrieve` function I need to be able to pass in a pointer to a slice (of any type) that Gorm can populate when the query is run.

I am currenrly refactoring this from a version that did have a separate function for retrieval for each of the API endpoints, but obviosuly that is inefficent and makes it harder to perform any refactor.

So is what I am asking at all possible?

Comment: Change returnObject type to `interface{}`. As for the type error `[]T` is not `[]I` even more so `*[]T` is not `*[]I`. Neither of those types have the same underlying type so you can't even convert one to the other using the conversion expression `T(v)`. https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Note that while it's possible to use a value of `T` as `I` if `T` implements `I`, it does not mean that you also can use `[]T` as `[]I` and therefore you can't use `[]interface{}` as a catch-all for *any* slice type, that's just not gonna work.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for that. It made be realise what I was not doing correctly. I have modified my code and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkopriva (and having a break from looking at the code) I was able to work out how get a resuable retrieve function.

As stated in the comments, I was trying to compare `[]T` with `[]I` which is not going to work. So I refactored by code to use a table name in the GORM chain which means that the result can now be an interface and this passed back as a return item instead of a pointer.

So now my `retrieve` method looks like:

```
func (v1 *ApiV1) retrieve(tableName string, fieldName string, name string) ([]interface{}, int) {

    // create var to hold the http status
    var httpStatus int = http.StatusOK
    var result []interface{}

    // determine if a name has been passed
    if name == "" {
        v1.app.DB.Find(result)
    } else {

        // look for the name in the database
        v1.app.DB.Table(tableName).Where(fieldName+" = ?", name).Order("id DESC").First(&result)

        // if the name cannot be found then set the status to 404
        if len(result) == 0 {
            httpStatus = http.StatusNotFound
        }
    }

    return result, httpStatus
}
```

The downside of this is that I have to pass in the name of the DB table to query, which *was* inferred from the result object. As I am not likely to change tables this is not too much of an inconvenience.

I also had to add an `ORDER` to the chain to get around an MSSQL problem when using GORM.

So now the API function looks like:

```
func (v1 *ApiV1) getImage(c *gin.Context) {

    // call method to retrieve the items from the database
    images, httpStatus := v1.retrieve("images", "name", c.Param("name"))

    c.JSON(
        httpStatus,
        images,
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my initial suggestion? i.e. changing `returnObject` type to `interface{}`. The `interface{}` *is*, ultimately, what the gorm methods accept as a paramter, including `.First` and `.Find`, right? So why not pass a value of that type from your function to gorm? When you're passing `interface{}` from one function to another, it's underlying dynamic value ain't gonna randomly change, it's still gonna be `*[]db.Image` if that's what you pass to `retrieve`! So do try https://play.golang.com/p/TjyBTIP1JsL please.

Comment: To (maybe) clarify this more: `var v interface{} = &[]db.Image{}` *is* OK and *will* compile. On the other hand `var v []interface{} = []db.Image{}` *is not* ok and *will not* compile, and neither will `var v *[]interface{} = &[]db.Image{}`!

Comment: In the first example `v` is an interface type and you can set its value to anything that implements that interface, however in the second case `v` is a *slice* type, regardless of what the type of the slice's element is, you have use the exact same type when setting `v`, same goes for pointer types. Just because a type is a pointer to an interface or a slice of interfaces does not mean that you can set it to a value of pointer to anything that implements the interface or slice of anything that implements the interface respectively.